# Is there a way to check if an image exists before setting the image source in React when the image source has concatenated variables?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a component that contains an image with a dynamic source. It's dynamic in that it takes 3 props that get concatenated into the URL of the image. No matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to stop giving me the error, 'Cannot find module' for images that don't exist.

I have tried checking to see if the image exists with the image-exists package and using ajax to check if the image exists. I have also tried adding onError to change the state from the URL.

```
import React from "react";

export class Drawing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { src: "" };
        this.setSource = this.setSource.bind(this);
    }

    setSource() {
        this.setState({
            src: require(`../../../../img/products/${this.props.type}/models/${this.props.product}-${this.props.model.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase()}-specs-drawing.png`)
        });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setSource();
    }

    render() {
        return <img src={this.state.src} alt="Specification Drawing" />;
    }
}
```

It almost seems as the the componentWillMount is getting called every time I change the dropdown selection. The dropdown changes the model which will change the image source based on the dropdown. It is showing the image correctly only if the image for that path exists. Otherwise it gives me the error, 'Cannot find module ...image-path'.

Comment: have you tried wrapping `require(\`...\`)` in a try catch block before passing it to `setState` in `setSource`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a simple `try/catch` block :

```
setSource() {
    try{
        const src = require(`../../../../img/products/${this.props.type}/models/${this.props.product}-${this.props.model.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase()}-specs-drawing.png`)
        this.setState({ src });
    }
    catch(err){
        //Do whatever you want when the image failed to load here
    }
}
```

Using this you can define the behavior of your application if the image loading failed into the `catch` block without having your program crashing

Comment: what if the image is from aws? I tried this and didn't work.

Comment: I have a similar issue except in my case it is wrapped in an if statement with a hasImage flag. When hasImage evaluates to false, the require still attempts to add the non-existant image to the page.  `let hasImage = false; if (hasImage) { myImage = require(...) });`

Answer (score 5):

Use the Javascript promise function to check whether image is exist or not.

try something like this.

```
const checkImage = path =>
 new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve({path, status: 'ok'});
    img.onerror = () => resolve({path, status: 'error'});

    img.src = path;
});
```

Comment: promise unknown is not assignable to type string? show your full work please

Comment: @tatsu It is on your side. You probably miss the `await` or the `.then` on the return of `checkImage` call.
If you use TS or flow, you can type the Promise like `new Promise<{path: string, status: 'ok' | 'error'}>(resolve => /* ... */)` to not have the "promise unknown".

Answer (score 1):

i did the following thing and it works smoothly

1.first you need a function which returns t/f for checking if your img url exists like this :

(i used axios , you can use simple promise)

```
export function CheckImage(path) {
  axios
    .get(path)
    .then(() => {
      return true;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return false;
    });
}
```

2.then in your img tag ,src attribute do this :

(path is the path to your image or url/ mainImage is your sample image path didnt exists)

```
      <img
        src={CheckImage(path) ? path : mainImage}
        alt={...}
      />
```